# Installing a MySQL database onto an external harddrive

Tags: mysql, external, hard-drive

I've been attempting to get a database onto an external hard drive to store a list of about 500,000 icons, and I'm running into an issue trying to run my script to import them all to a database.  I'm trying to follow the instructions on this blog http://blog.gamatam.com/2009/05/creating-mysql-database-on-external.html
but when I get to the step to execute mysql_install_db --ldata=data it gives me an error saying

Installing MySQL system tables...

110428 18:17:45 [Warning] Can't create test file /media/FreeAgentDisk/data/ubuntu.lower-test
110428 18:17:45 [Warning] Can't create test file /media/FreeAgentDisk/data/ubuntu.lower-test

Installation of system tables failed! Examine the logs in
/media/FreeAgentDisk/data for more information.

and in addition there are no log files created

Comment: What operating system?  Have you mounted the drive?

Comment: 32 Bit Ubuntu v10.04, the drive gets mounted to /media automatically when it is plugged in, and I am successfully able to browse it and create folders

Comment: were you ever able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your drive has the correct permissions and that the mysql daemon has access to it. Furthermore the logs from the said position would be helpful.